# Vue - Composable and emit - Passing function from parent to grandchild

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am new to Vue and I have recently started to use Composition api.
I understand that emit in Option Api but I am not really sure what is the benefit in Composition Api...

For example, in OptionApi:
Parent.vue

```
export default {
  name: 'Parent',
  Methods: {
    sayHi (name) {
      console.log('Hi!' + name);
    },
  },
};
```

Child.vue

```
// Pass parent method to GrandChild.vue
```

GradeChild.vue

```
export default {
  name: 'GradeChild',
  Methods: {
    emitToChild () {
      this.$emit('childCompSayHi', this.name);
    },
  },
};
```

In Composition Api:
Parent.vue

```
export default {
  name: 'Parent',
  setup() {
    const { name } = useName();
    const sayHi = () => {
      console.log('Hi!' + name.value);
    };
    return {
      sayHi,
    };
  },
};
```

GrandChild.vue

```
export default {
  name: 'GradeChild',
  setup() {
    const { setName } = useName();
    setName(name);
  },
};
```

useName.js

```
const name = ref('');

export const useColorPicker = () => {
  const setName = (newName) => {
    name.value = newName;
  };

  return {
    name,
    setName,
  };
};
```

Correct me if I am wrong but Composable can do the same thing without emit, right?
If we have a parent component who passes a function down to a grandchild to get grandchild's data, we can just use composable and create a setter function and use it in the grandchild and then use the variable in the parent component without having to pass the function all components down, no?

Comment: sounds like a problem that state management (aka vuex) would solve?

Comment: `const name = ref('')` - when done in module scope, this will result in global state that is shared among all components, not specific parent/child, regardless of whether a composable is used

Comment: @EstusFlask Right, you are correct..Is there a way to pass function down from parent to grandchild and get data back without doing a chain of emits?

Comment: Yes. Pass a ref (local one, not global as in your case) to a child with provide/inject

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into it.